# 'Font Awesome' в медиа запросах

Tags: css, fontawesome

Как уменьшить шрифтовые иконки 'Font Awesome' в медиа запросах, возможно ли это вообще?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уменьшайте font-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример:

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
}

footer .fa {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 420px){
  footer .fa {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
 <footer>
   <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-git" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </footer>
```

уменьшайте\увеличивайте `font-size` 
с `420px` шрифт увеличивается в 2 раза (размер иконок  в 2 раза)

Answer (score 0):

Изменяйте свойство `font-size` для настройки размера:

```
#elementID {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272372/how-to-style-icon-color-size-and-shadow-of-font-awesome-icons) можно увидеть анологичный вопрос и ответ на него.